# Selecting the individuals from a group of jQuery elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I use jquery to select all my text inputs:

```
var inputs = $('#form input[type="text"]');
```

They are wrapped in jQuery. I can do whatever I want with them.

```
inputs.css('height', '1000px');
//muhahaha!
```

As a group they abide. But I seem to be missing something. I know I can see each one individually as if it was an array of objects.

```
console.log(inputs[0]);
// <input type="text" />
```

But the above output is just the html; when I do that it's no longer a jQuery object :(

```
inputs[0].css('font-size', '100px');
// Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'css'
```

How do I continue to use jquery's methods on the individual without having to wrap each element again, or is this not possible for some strange, dark, inexplicable reason?

Didn't even know where to begin searching this one, and my jQuery journey has not lead me to the answer thus far. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this page: [jQuery Filtering](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/filtering/)

```
inputs.eq(0).css('font-size', '100px');
```

Should do the trick in this case

Comment: Incredibly simple as I expected. Is this technically doing another query? It just seems like, intuitively, one could use an array index...

Comment: Quote from the `.eq()` link if you follow the link in the answer: Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .eq() method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the set.

Answer (score 1):

see this [function .eq() in Jquery-API](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

When access the Dom-Node-Collection in JQuery via Array-Index, you get the RAW Dom-Elements, if you select the index with the given method above, you'll get feature-enhanced jQuery-Wrapped-Elements.
See docs.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid wrapping each element again(`$(inputs[0]).css('font-size', '100px')`)

would be using pure JavaScript. Example: `inputs[0].style.fontSize = "100px";`